# sublime tab right-click menu to add a save all options

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I recently upgraded the version, there is a need to transplant function, but this feature I do not know because it is installed what plug-in? So now need to manually add, I know you can use shortcut keys binding, but my shortcut keys are occupied, and if you continue to set up but it is not convenient to use.

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+*+*"], "command": "save_all" }
```

[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17SYE.png)

[needs improvement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPUya.png)

Answer (score 0):

Find the Default.sublime-package file,

rename Default.sublime-package to a zip file and unzip.

There we find the file Tab Context.sublime-menu and Context.sublime-menu

Add `{"command": "save_all", "caption": "Save All"},`

The effect is as follows:

[Tab Context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nS2tB.png)

[Context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEN42.png)